# How to update highchart every minute

Tags: javascript, node.js, highcharts, ejs

My data is coming from MYSQL Database which is getting live data. I am not using json or php.I want it to start updating every minute from 9 am till 5pm. I have tried methods like setInterval and setTimeout and chart.redraw() but cant seem to make it work. I have also tried the dynamic update chart in highcharts link is here
https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/dynamic-update but cant seem to convert random data syntax to my database data. my code is :

````
<head>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/drag-panes.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/oi chart.css">

</head>
<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
</figure>

<script type="text/javascript">
  
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
        chart: {
            height: (1 / 2 * 100) + '%' // 1:2 ratio
        },
        rangeSelector: {
            enabled: true,
            selected: customRange,
            buttons: [{
                type: 'day',
                count: 1,
                text: '1D'
            }, {
                type: 'week',
                count: 1,
                text: '1W'
            }, {
                type: 'week',
                count: 2,
                text: '2W'
            }, {
                type: 'month',
                count: 1,
                text: '1M'
            }, {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }]
        },
        time: {
            timezoneOffset: timezone
        },
        title: {
            text: chartTitle,

        },
        subtitle: {
            text: subTitle,
        },
        yAxis: {
            offset: 60,
            title: {
                text: 'Open Interest'
            },
            resize: {
                enabled: true
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },

        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle'
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {


                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                label: {
                    connectorAllowed: false
                },

            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Expected',
            data: [<% for(var i=0; i < expected_data.length; i++) { %> [<%= expected_data[i] %>], <% } %>].sort()

        }, {
            name: 'Actual',
            data: [<% for(var i=0; i < actual_data.length; i++) { %> [<%= actual_data[i] %>], <% } %>].sort()

        }],


        responsive: {
            rules: [{
                condition: {
                    maxWidth: 500
                },
                chartOptions: {
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'horizontal',
                        align: 'center',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                    }
                }
            }]
        }

    });
</script>

</html>```
````

Comment: You're conflating server- and client-side logic. The data for your chart is being printed directly on the page by the server, and so using `setInterval` to redraw the chart does not work, as new data is not fetched from the server. I would suggest you fetch new data from the server when redrawing is needed.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Create an endpoint on your server that serves chart data. Use `fetch()` to retrieve new data at a fixed interval. Redraw chart with that new data.

Comment: can you give me an example of this using the code above I am new to highchart and node so cannot grasp fully without an example.

Comment: Unfortunately this makes your question grow in scope a lot, since it involves several different tasks (read my previous comment). Read more about creating an endpoint on your server that returns chart data, and learn how to use the Fetch API. Tutorials are everywhere.

Comment: @ness I totally agree with the above. From the Highcharts side, I can share a demo showing how to fetch data from the server and create a base chart. The rest of the work depends on your implementation. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/huc3g6zw/

Comment: can I do the above for multiple series also?

Comment: @ness yes, why not?